# Setting up AutoScaling using GUI based interface on Amazon EC2 service

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We want to setup/configure AutoScaling on Amazon EC2 services using some GUI Intrerface. Is it possible to do?

As per our research, we found that it can be setup via API Queries or commandline tools only. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't actually have an answer, but I'm just curious, what language/stack do you plan on developing in?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.  You can create the elastic load balancers and turn CloudWatch on for the instances using the GUI console, but to set up autoscaling config, groups, and triggers you have to use the [AutoScaling API tools](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2535&categoryID=88).

Your other option would be to use a third party provisioning vendor like [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com/) that adds more GUI provisioning and scaling kinds of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so far Amazon does not offer a GUI for Auto Scaling. You do have to use the command line tools (in conjunction with CloudWatch to setup monitoring to add/remove auto scaling instances), or use the APIs. In addition to Scalr you can also try
[EZAutoScaling](http://www.ezautoscaling.com) (only does Auto Scaling GUI, very cheap) and [Ylastic](http://www.ylastic.com) (does Auto Scaling GUI plus a ton more, a little more expensive).
Disclosure: I was slightly involved in EZAutoScaling.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what Ernest said, it is indeed correct. Amazon autoscaling features works pretty well. But in order to use it you will need to do API calls.

However, if you want out-of-the-box autoscaling, you should consider using a third party cloud management platforms such as RightScale or [**Scalr**](http://scalr.net) (where I work). You will be able to scale based on CPU, Ram, Disk io, Network io... The autoscaling process itself is managed a bit differently. You can have more info on the [wiki](http://wiki.scalr.net/FAQ/Scalr_vs_AWS_auto-scaling).